# Close dialog jquery after click on anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a very small problem here, i'm new at jQuery so hope you can help me, i've tried a lot of things, and search everything but can't get it working, my code is:

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        // main.js
    var clip = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById("copy-button"), {
      moviePath: "http://www.reembolseja.com/js/ZeroClipboard.swf"
    } );

    clip.on( "load", function(client) {
      // alert( "movie is loaded" );

      client.on( "complete", function(client, args) {
        // `this` is the element that was clicked
        //this.style.display = "none";
        var dialog = $('<div id="dialog"> <span class="detalhesCupom">Cupom copiado com sucesso!</span><span class="detalhesCupomCode" id="fe_text">' + args.text +'</span><br />Agora que o cupom já foi copiado, você já pode começar a comprar, clique no botão abaixo para ser redirecionado ao site da loja e boas compras!<br /><a href="/go2store.php?id=<?php echo $row['retailer_id']; ?>" target="_blank" class="submit" style="margin:10px auto; float:none;">Ir a Loja</a><div id="closeDialog">fechar</div></div>').fadeIn();
    dialog.css({
        position:'fixed',
        top: 100,
        left: '50%',
        width: '420px',
        height: '270px',
        'margin-left': '-210px',
        'z-index' : 99999
        });
    $('body').append(dialog);
      } );
    } );
                });

    $('#closeDialog').live('click', function() {
         $('#dialog').dialog( "close" );
    });
```

So, here i have a button that when the user click, will copy the hidden code, then there is a button anchor that will redirect the user to another page (opening on blank target), the problem is that after the click, the dialog box didnt close at all, stay there and there's no way to close.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: any error in the browser console

Comment: Hi, i'm using 1.4.2, no errors on console. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using a [dialog widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/), so just hide/remove the dialog element

```
$('#closeDialog').live('click', function() {
     $('#dialog').remove();//or call .hide()
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, i dont know what i was doing wrong, teh code looks similar the one i tried, you're my hero :)

Answer (score 0):

`$('#dialog')` is not an dialog. you can't use `.dialog("close")` on this.
instant use somethink like this

```
$('#closeDialog').live('click', function () {
    $('#dialog').fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```